# Same compiler creating different behaviors on different OS

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

Some of us in my company are arguing about it. Given a source code and a compiler (compiled with same flags/switches) is it possible that the compiler will create binaries that will have different behaviors in different OSes?

Concretely, we've a C# project that must be run in Windows XP and Windows 7, both 32 bit. The compiler is VS 2008. There is a solution file (*.sln) that contains all necessary files, assemblies, projects etc that we use to build the software.

Is it possible that if the code (the same solution file) is compiled in VS 2008 (with same flags/switches, as it is the same solution file) in XP will produce a binary which will have **behavioral difference** than the compiled binary in Windows 7?

By behavioral difference I mean, in a given situation...

- The XP build will run as expected in XP
- The Win 7 build will run as expected in Win 7
- The XP build may cause a bug (may be a crash, or some unexpected behavior) in Win 7 and vice versa

The project is too huge to come up with a little test project. I want to know what are the cases (if any) when the above is true.

Comment: Build the binaries in question. Do a binary compare. See what is different. I expect they will be the same. Make sure build release versions only. Otherwise, machine specific information is added to binaries and pdb.

Comment: Calling a native API method that only exists in Windows 7 comes to mind.

Comment: Recently to rebuild lost source code, I compared Windows XP built binaries and Windows 7 64-bit and found no differences.

Comment: ExamDiff Pro is how I compare directories of assemblies.

Comment: No, everything is dependent upon the **compiler** (the version, the switches, etc.). It has nothing to do with the operating system or environment.

Comment: Sure they'll behave differently.  .NET programs have a heavy dependency on OS supplied components.  Pretty obvious in a GUI app, they don't even *look* the same.  Another obvious one is a 64-bit version of Win7 vs a 32-bit version of XP.  And UAC.  And session 0 isolation.  Etcetera.

Comment: @HansPassant; But that is the run-time environment. The generated assemblies will not behave differently.

Comment: @HansPassant: i'm aware of the run time behavioral difference. but they can't be eliminated by compiling the same code with same compiler is target OS, right?

Comment: @AndrewBarber: the funny part is, there is no bug. but some of my team members have the misconception that may be to test in windows 7, the build should come from windows 7 machine. in reality, there is no such proof that a build from windows 7 performs as expected in windows 7 testing.

Comment: Right.  The odds that the compiler is affected by the OS are miniscule.  Never heard of such as case.

Comment: Your colleagues are wrong. :-) You might mention to them that if their theory were correct, Windows 8 would be unable to run any applications on the day that it was released! If they find/have found such a case, then they've surely found a bug in the compiler. Then you have a *really* interesting question on your hands. Be sure to post it here for our amusement and the rep gain!

Comment: @CodyGray: thanks for the windows 8 example. :)

Comment: We develop on Windows 7 64-bit, we build on either Window XP or Windows 7 32-bit, depending who is the QA, we build and deploy from a Windows 7 32/64-bit or Windows XP, depending who is the assigned lead for deployment. We deploy to Windows 7 32/64-bit and Windows XP. Never had any behavioral differences. This is a non-issue in .NET. PERIOD.

Comment: @AMissico: thanks for sharing your experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given identical installations of VS2008, including service packs, and given identical frameworks, including service packs, on the test machines, the answer is no.

However, this does not mean that there are not tasks that the application performs that will behave differently on the different operating systems.

You must also consider that the operating system's different responses to the application (firewall, DEP, UAC, etc) could expose flaws in the application on one operating system that are not present on another.

And then there is the unmanaged code issue, which is another topic altogether. And, while we're at it, native OS calls from your app could cause instability.

But none of this is due to the compiler given the constraints in the opening sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: no.

It is more common that your application fails due to different circumstances. For instance, missing libraries, files, registry keys; unplugged devices.

Hopefully you're not doing something strange like this ;)

```
if (DateTime.Now.Year != 2012)
   throw new Exception();
```

Comment: Why would that code produce different behavior depending on compilation time? `DateTime.Now` is not a constant value embedded into the code at compile-time, it's read dynamically at run-time.

Comment: @Code Gray: rephrased, was not what I meant:)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no. Regardless of the machine or operating system, the nature of the compiler is to generate the same assembly based of the same code.

Imagine what would happen if this wasn't true? You would have to have separate build machines with various operating system and with various service pack or whatever.